# run Job Scheduler in offline mode, When no Wifi or Data Connection

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

**when no data conncetion or no wifi state i want to run JobScheduler in OREO**

```
        val componentName = ComponentName(this, JobScheduleService::class.java)
        val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(12, componentName)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
                .build()

        val jobScheduler = getSystemService(
                Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
```

Comment: we cannot run schedular in offline..

Answer (score 2):

Consider working with [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)
It's a replacement for `AlarmManager` and `JobSchedulers`.

P.S: WorkManager has an easy answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you.. i have seen those too.. they also required network..

for now in jobscheduler

setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)

Comment: Thank you @unline .. I found a solution after a long Research, I am using a StartForeGroundService With Wakeful Receiver..in offline it woks great..